# What does the CPU *really* do during memory instructions?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpufreq

I was recently testing out the linux cpufreq module and noticed that regardless of whether I was running a CPU intensive benchmark or a memory intensive benchmark, the cpufreq module always chose the maximum frequency.

I understand that the governor plays an important role in deciding the frequency settings. Thus I tested it out with both ondemand and conservative governors and found the results to be the almost the same (conservative has a tiny climb to max frequency whereas ondemand just picks max frequency immediately).

This raised the question regarding what the CPU is actually doing during a load/store.
We all know that memory runs significantly slower than the CPU and load/store instructions typically take several CPU cycles to complete.

**edit**: I realize that many such load/store instructions will probably hit the cache. What about ones that don't?

What is the CPU actually doing during these cycles? Is it busy-waiting or idle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms CPU, processor, and processor core are very key in your question. What you probably mean to ask is, what is the *processor core* really doing while it waits for memory.

In most modern Intel processors, it begins executing another branch of instructions. This is called [hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading).

In most other processors, it essentially spends time in a wait-state.

Comment: Just to add to  hyper-threading: If one of the treads need to wait for memory and the other tread does not, then it indeed executes the other tread. If both do non-memory stuff one has to wait (there is only one core after all, despite it showing two treads). If both need to access non-cached memory both wait.

Comment: I was running a simulation under very strict parameters which included a single core on an in-order pipeline. I do not have hyper-threading on my processor. Given these conditions, what would the processor be most likely to do during a load/store?

Comment: @user1761555 *it essentially spends time in a wait-state.*